# how to stop overlapping of divisions in HTML/CSS during zoom

Tags: html, css

I need to place tables that are given a class ID in various parts of the browser. My problem happens when zooming out. The divisions start overlapping. Is there a way to make it so they don't overlap besides making them farther apart (that way when I'm zoomed in they are close together).

Here's an example code of the CSS:

So is there something else besides `position:absolute` I can use, or something in addition to that that will make a difference?

```
#UB_37{
 position:absolute; 
 top: 144px;
 left: 646px;
 width:32px;
 height:252px;
transform:rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
 -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
 -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: Dint understand your problem exactly.
But "position:relative" is an other option try that once.

Comment: Paste your HTML mark up or jsfiddle. so it might be easier to understand.

Comment: What do you wanna achieve with such huge table with all useless values?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tJxE9/ I don find any error in zooming over there..

Comment: Yeah em might be helpful. Check this link out for more help on em.
http://joshnh.com/2011/07/are-you-using-ems-with-your-media-queries/

Comment: Using em instead of px will help in relative positioning of the divs.